# How do you check "if not null" with Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How do you check if a field *is not null* with Eloquent?

I tried `Model::where('sent_at', 'IS NOT', DB::raw('null'))->...` but it gives `IS NOT` as a binding instead of a comparison.

This is what `DB::getQueryLog()` says about it:

```
  'query' => string 'select * from my_table where sent_at = ? and profile_id in (?, ?) order by created_at desc' (length=101)
  'bindings' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'IS NOT' (length=6)
      1 => int 1
      2 => int 4
```

Comment: You could try using `!=` instead of IS NOT.

Comment: @JaTochNietDan The != operator does not work with NULL values. Per the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html): "You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL."

Answer (score 602, accepted):

Eloquent has a method for that (Laravel 4.*/5.*);

```
Model::whereNotNull('sent_at')
```

Laravel 3:

```
Model::where_not_null('sent_at')
```

Comment: I need to check the null at deleted field, so I changed this into 
    `whereNull('deleted_at')`
and I got my query running.

Comment: Another [undocumented](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries) feature. Well, unless you count the API docs, but Laravel's main documentation makes no mention of it.

Comment: The `whereNotNull()` method (and several others that were undocumented previously) were added to the documentation in version 5.1: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses .

Comment: @aross but in Query Builder, not in Eloquent (Laravel 5.1)

Comment: @pmiranda not sure what you mean, but my comment was 4 years ago and about Laravel 4, nowadays we're at Laravel 6. I guess the situation changed. Although Laravel's main documentation is still not very complete, it feels more like a bunch of guides.

Comment: "whereNotNull()" works in Laravel 7 and 8 also. I have also tested it with Lumen 8. Thanks.

Comment: If you're testing `deleted_at IS NOT NULL` this is a default filter for all queries if your models `use SoftDeletes;`

Answer (score 25):

If someone like me want to do it with query builder in Laravel 5.2.23 it can be done like ->

```
 $searchResultQuery = Users::query(); 
 $searchResultQuery->where('status_message', '<>', '', 'and'); // is not null
 $searchResultQuery->where('is_deleted', 'IS NULL', null, 'and'); // is null
```

Or with scope in model :

```
public function scopeNotNullOnly($query){

    return $query->where('status_message', '<>', '');
}
```

Comment: what does `'and'` stands for?

Comment: Actually here 'and' does nothing but it would do if first parameter would be an array. Here is the method prototype : `public function where($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and'); `and location - `".....\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php"`

Answer (score 20):

**We can use**

```
Model::whereNotNull('sent_at');
```

**Or**

```
Model::whereRaw('sent_at is not null');
```

Answer (score 14):

If you wanted to use the [DB facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#retrieving-results):

`DB::table('table_name')->whereNotNull('sent_at')->get();`

Answer (score 12):

I see this question is a bit old but I ran across it looking for an answer.  Although I did not have success with the answers here I think this might be because I'm on **PHP 7.2** and **Laravel 5.7.** or possible because I was just playing around with some data on the CLI using Laravel Tinker.

I have some things I tried that worked for me and others that did not that I hope will help others out.

---

I did not have success running:

```
    MyModel::whereNotNull('deleted_by')->get()->all();             // []
    MyModel::where('deleted_by', '<>', null)->get()->all();        // []
    MyModel::where('deleted_by', '!=', null)->get()->all();        // []
    MyModel::where('deleted_by', '<>', '', 'and')->get()->all();   // []
    MyModel::where('deleted_by', '<>', null, 'and')->get()->all(); // []
    MyModel::where('deleted_by', 'IS NOT', null)->get()->all();    // []
```

All of the above returned an empty array for me

---

I did however have success running:

```
    DB::table('my_models')->whereNotNull('deleted_by')->get()->all(); // [ ... ]
```

This returned all the results in an array as I expected.  Note: you can drop the `all()` and get back a *Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection* instead of an array if you prefer.

Answer (score 7):

in **laravel 5.4** this code `Model::whereNotNull('column')` was not working you need to add `get()` like this one `Model::whereNotNull('column')->get();` this one works fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

Checking "**not null**"

```
Model::whereNotNull('column1');
```

Checking "**null**"

```
Model::whereNull('column1');
```

Another solution is using `whereRaw()`

```
Model::whereRaw("column1 IS NOT NULL");
Model::whereRaw("column1 IS NULL");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by simply following:

```
Model::whereNotNull('sent_at')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can also use raw query.**

**Remember:** Reports is my model and I am using where raw, the best thing of the raw query is that you can use multiple types of operators such as AND, OR etc just by passing as a string.

For example: WHERE condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3 ...;

---

```
Reports::whereRaw("column1 IS NOT NULL AND column2 IS NOT NULL");
```

The above query will be executed as:

> Select * from reports where column IS NOT NULL AND column2 IS NOT NULL.

For more understanding of **IS Null** and **IS not null** operators:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
$deliveryTo = DeliveryTo::where([
            ['delete_flg', '=', 0],
            ['area_id', '=', 1],
            ['area_id', '!=', NULL],
        ])->get();
```

Comment: There is no explanation in your answer! Code only answers are never good to the site!

Answer (score -16):

If you want to search deleted record (Soft Deleted Record), do not use Eloquent Model Query.

Use the Db::table query instead. E.g.:

Instead of:

```
$stu = Student::where('rollNum', '=', $rollNum . '-' . $nursery)->first();
```

Use:

```
$stu = DB::table('students')->where('rollNum', '=', $newRollNo)->first();
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question. Besides that, you don't necessary needs to use `Db::table` to find the soft deleted records. You could filter them with the method `withTrashed()`, like is told in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the demanded question.